# OnClick event on TextView stops RippleEffect on CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I have a TextView inside a CardView. When enabling the ripple effect for Lollipop on the CardView by adding a OnClick event and adding the property:

`android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

It works fine. But after adding a OnClick event to the TextView, the ripple effect still shows up when I click outside of the TextView, but it won't show when clicking on the TextView area.

Is there away to show the ripple even when I click the TextView?

Here is xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/news_card"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="Test String"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

    View v = findViewById (R.id.news_card);
    v.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override public void onClick (final View v) {

        }
    });

    View textView = findViewById (R.id.text);
    textView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override public void onClick (final View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The ripple should only show on the element that handles the click. If the entire card isn't clickable, the entire card shouldn't show a ripple.

Comment: On a user's perspective, the entire card is clickable. But when user clicks on the TextView, it has to do some extra logic first before passing that on to the card's onclick event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to forward the pressed state and hotspot position through to the parent view.

```
// Since the host view actually supports clicks, you can return false
// from your touch listener and continue to receive events.
myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        // Convert to card view coordinates. Assumes the host view is
        // a direct child and the card view is not scrollable.
        float x = e.getX() + v.getLeft();
        float y = e.getY() + v.getTop();

        // Simulate motion on the card view.
        myCardView.drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);

        // Simulate pressed state on the card view.
        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                myCardView.setPressed(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                myCardView.setPressed(false);
                break;
        }

        // Pass all events through to the host view.
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works. But the animation is not as smooth as the default behavior. I ended up removing the onClickListener on the TextView and implement onTouchListener to do what onClickListener does and return false to allow the CardView to show the ripple effect.